# How to take a string in a function call, and remove everything around it, in Emacs

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

I have some function calls like

`scan_config.iFOV = xmlFile->getIntVal("iFOV");`

Now I want to make a test XML file. I want to take the iFOV part, and make a tag automaticly, so it would look like this:

`<iFOV>`

Bonus points if you can also tell me how to get a closing tag also.

I think I need a regexp, but I can't figure out what it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`query-replace-regexp`: Replace `^.*"\(.*\)".*` with `<\1></\1>`